# alter default priviliges for schema

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm using Redshift and I'm trying to make all tables created by a user_A, regardless of the schema where the table is created, are granted read access to group group_G.

I ran the following query according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR user_A GRANT 
SELECT ON TABLES TO GROUP group_G;
```

but whenever I create a new table and try to access it with any user from group_G, I receive `permission denied for schema`.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: what are group_g's access privileges for the schema?  To be able to access a table in a schema the requestor needs to have USAGE granted to them for the schema.  Is this the case?

Comment: I didn't specify any. By reading the documentation, I thought that by omitting the schema, any table created, regardsless of the schema, would have the permissions properly set, including a GRANT USAGE

Comment: I wasn't speaking of the default_acl but rather pre-existing grants on the schema.  A user doesn't have permission to access a schema by default (unless it is the public schema) and would need to be granted USAGE access to view any objects in the schema.  Without this the user cannot access through the schema to view the table even if they have select access on the table.  This will give them the ability to see what other tables exist in the schema though they cannot access them without permissions to the tables.  If you don't want this you will need to address this another way.

Comment: The schemas are generated dynamically and I wasn't willing to alter the generate flow and was expecting to apply the grant usage step via default privileges. Am I correct in understanding that this is not possible ?

Comment: So does the group have usage access to the schema?  I'd hate to be barking up the wrong tree.  Default_acl is applied on things that are created by the user but the schema already exists.  So creating a table in an existing schema won't change change the schema's privileges.

Comment: No. It doesn't. I was expecting the permissions to be set somehow using the default_acl. I'm sorry if I'm misuing some terms here

Comment: You're good.  The default_acl can only set a schema's permissions when it is being create.  To be able to use a table in schema the user has to have USAGE rights on the schema OR they can gain access through a view in a schema where they do have USAGE rights.  Not sure that helps you but wanted to point it out.

Comment: Got it. Thaks for the thorough explanation, Bill